# Javascript module export unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, export

I have got issue Module export unexpected token error when I am trying to create an module pure javascript and import it to static html to use.

```js
const Accordion = {
  items: [],
  listeners: [],

  init() {
    const accordions = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');

    Array.from(accordions).forEach((accordion) => {
      const items = accordion.getElementsByClassName('accordion-item');
      Array.from(items).forEach((item) => {
        const title = item.getElementsByClassName('accordion-title');
        title[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
          item.classList.toggle('open');
        });
        this.listeners.push(title[0]);
        this.items.push(item);
      });
    });
  },

  destroy() {
    this.listeners.forEach((listener) => {
      listener.removeEventListener('click', () => {});
    });
  },
  
};

export default Accordion;
```

```html
<div class="xs-12">
        <div class="content-title">Accordion</div>
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <div class="accordion-title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="accordion-details">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <div class="accordion-title">Title 2</div>
                <div class="accordion-details">
                    Shankle strip steak pork buffalo biltong ground round rump tongue.
                    Strip steak alcatra turkey pig biltong bresaola. Venison tri-tip andouille,
                    landjaeger pork chop picanha tongue short ribs sirloin salami bacon bresaola.
                    Spare ribs burgdoggen pork loin, prosciutto cow sirloin venison pancetta.
                    Biltong drumstick jowl cow doner boudin.
                    Jerky shoulder buffalo pork kielbasa bresaola shank spare ribs pork chop.
                    Jerky pig salami buffalo pork chop fatback bacon tenderloin t-bone
                    pastrami burgdoggen shoulder pork loin ham hock.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <div class="accordion-title">Title 3</div>
                <div class="accordion-details">
                    Spare ribs bacon shank sirloin. Chicken ribeye pork,
                    tri-tip boudin short ribs bresaola prosciutto pastrami brisket pancetta.
                    Ham fatback strip steak chicken prosciutto hamburger salami jowl sausage
                    tongue tenderloin biltong. Sirloin bresaola corned beef flank.
                    Doner ribeye jowl meatloaf, andouille pork loin picanha meatball cupim
                    swine fatback flank filet mignon. Beef ribs pancetta t-bone,
                    tail tri-tip filet mignon jowl kielbasa meatball frankfurter boudin strip steak.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
(function() {
    console.log('jump into loading global js files');

    requirejs(["../js/accordion"]);
 
 })();
</script>
```

Here is the code : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2lose/v4h8L6x0/2/)

But it got error unexpected token export module.
Could someone can help me take a look, please?

Edit: Add the code to import module.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where is the import?

Comment: @joyBlanks: Actually, i was imported this module by create an index.js :

(function() {
    console.log('JS Loaded');

    requirejs(["../js/accordion"]);
 
 })();

Then, import index.js into html.

Comment: The problem is with `requirejs`, not `export`... You haven't defined it at all!

Comment: I don't think you can use es6 modules (`export xxx`) with `requirejs` - one usually uses `import` statement with es6 modules - which browser are you using?

Comment: @JaromandaX: I am using latest chrome

Comment: so why are you using requirejs when you are using ES6 modules syntax?

Comment: @JaromandaX: well, you think that I should not using ES6 with requirejs ?
So, should I only use pure javascript (Vanilla) to create an function or object, then just need to call it when the DOM ready? 
If I want to use ES6 module syntax, I can create module and using *import syntax like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: `you think that I should not using ES6 with requirejs` - I'd be surprised if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 on your fiddle and check where the error comes from:

```
(index):61 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Let's check what is at line 61 of index:

```
export default Accordion;
```

Now, why would that be an issue? Well, because *native* javascript modules have to be placed inside of script tags that are marked as `type="module"`.
You are using requireJs, which seems to be importing your javascript file by simply placing the code from your file inside of 'window.onload', which results in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

    window.onload=function(){

const Accordion = {
  items: [],
  listeners: [],

  init() {
    const accordions = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');

    Array.from(accordions).forEach((accordion) => {
      const items = accordion.getElementsByClassName('accordion-item');
      Array.from(items).forEach((item) => {
        const title = item.getElementsByClassName('accordion-title');
        title[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
          item.classList.toggle('open');
        });
        this.listeners.push(title[0]);
        this.items.push(item);
      });
    });
  },

  destroy() {
    this.listeners.forEach((listener) => {
      listener.removeEventListener('click', () => {});
    });
  },
};

export default Accordion;


    }

  //]]></script>
```

So there is an `export` inside of a function... that is not valid syntax. Remove it and the code will run just fine.

If want to use native javascript modules, use the `import` syntax to import your module. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).